# In app billing: get user ID?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm just starting to play around with in app billing.  From the guide here:

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html

it tells you how to query what products have been purchased etc.  If the product is some sort of bundle of credits, the consumption of which is to be managed by the developer, some sort of ID is required to identify the google account used for the purchase, so that the developer can keep track of credit usage for that user (on whatever device they're using).

So the question is, as well as information regarding purchased products in the in app billing queries mentioned in above link, is it possible to get some sort of ID associated with the user account... something I can use to associate with the credits for onward management?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Google Saved Game services.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames